# PHP Security and License

Tags: php, whmcs

I want to secure my PHP code and use LICENSE for it. Something like that my software will work only for specific users servers that I provided license to them.

How can I use domain , IP, localkeyand expire date and generate license based on this for my own PHP software?

Please guide me and share your knowledge about whmcs or any other methods that it can cover my need.

Comment: WHMCS is web hosting, not software distribution.

Comment: FYI:  https://docs.whmcs.com/Licensing_Addon

Comment: Do You want to sell an obfuscated code to someone or only an access to Your application?

Comment: I want to secure my PHP with license. Something I’ll be able to add expiration license date that it will force users to pay otherwise they won’t be able to use my software or sell my software to others. I want to add client domain, IP, license key and based on this my PHP will work on user client servers.

Comment: In that case I think you need to run the code on your webpage and have your clients access the code with a API call or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

The WHMCS licensing addon allows you to validate domain, IP, filepath, and other values. You will need to integrate it into your application. Fundamentally though, you will also need to encode the files with ioncube or some other tool to reduce the chances of the code you distribute from being modified by your customers. The effectiveness of your licensing implementation depends a lot more on how effective you think ioncube is.

Comment: "depends a lot more on how effective you think ioncube is" - And even more on how well it's used Nate. If they just encode then code is compiled and has basic protection, but if a hacker manages to get at the compiled code, then as with any software, an attempt at decompilation could be made. They should at least enable obfuscation, but really need to use Dynamic Keys so that some of the code is encrypted without any decryption keys being stored. That's the route to  best code protection as long as they are smart about implementation of key generators. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.